# How to get the name "Gokila" in the below string using regex python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

"I hope you enjoyed the stay, Gokila!HOPE TO SEE YOU AGAIN Your compliment tickets are valid for 6 months from the date of issue."

Comment: What is the logic by which we would know where in the string to look for the name `Gokila`?  We need this information in order to formulate any kind of answer.

Comment: I want to know if this could be done with regex. Or any normal text split and slicing will do?

Comment: Your comment does not answer my question.

Comment: Anything after first ", " till "!" must be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can get match in the regex by accessing each group by it position number. In the regex which I provide bellow there is only one capturing parenthese.

```
 import re

 str = "I hope you enjoyed the stay, Gokila!HOPE TO SEE YOU AGAIN Your compliment tickets are valid for 6 months from the date of issue."
 matches = re.search(".*\s(.*)\!.*", str)

 print(matches.group(1))
 # Gokila
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.match` with a capture group:

```
inp = "I hope you enjoyed the stay, Gokila!HOPE TO SEE YOU AGAIN Your compliment tickets are valid for 6 months from the date of issue."
m = re.match(r'.*,\s+(\w+)\b.*', inp)
if m:
    print(m.groups(1)[0])
```

This prints:

```
Gokila
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=, )(?:\w+\s*)+(?=!)
```

This is under the assumption that there is a space after the comma before the name